# Uniqueness of minimum within interval

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

Assuming a smooth real valued function

$$
f(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$

with $x^{*}$ being a local minimum of $f$. Further let

$$
f^{(k)}(x) := \frac{d^k}{d x^k}f(x)
$$

be the first non-zero derivative of $f$ at $x^{*}$.

**Question**: Say I can show that $f^{(k)}$ is strictly positive on an interval containing $x^{*}$, does this imply that $x^{*}$ is the only minimum in this interval?

If yes, does this extend to the multidimensional case with $f(x):\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1$ be another minimum in that interval. Then there exists $x_2\in (x_1,x^*)$ such that
$$
0 = f'(x_1) - f'(x^*) = f''(x_2)(x_1-x^*),
$$
that is, $f''(x_2) = 0$. Now, by the same reasoning, there exists $x_3\in (x_2,x^*)$ such that $f'''(x_3) = 0$ and so on up to some $x_{k-1}$ for which $f^{(k-1)}(x_{k-1}) = 0$. Finally, there exists $x_k\in (x_{k-1},x^*)$ such that 
$$
0 = f^{(k-1)}(x_{k-1}) - f^{(k-1)}(x^*) = f^{(k)}(x_k)(x_{(k-1)} - x^*),
$$
which is impossible by your assumption.

EDIT: I don't know how this result might be generalized to the multi-dimensional situation.

Comment: So this means $x^{*}$ is guaranteed to be the only minimum in the interval?

Comment: The fact that you ask lets me conclude that you have not understood the proof.

Comment: Not completly, unfortunatly. I don't understand why $f'(x_1) - f'(x^{*}) = f''(x_2)(x_1 - x^{*})$? Why can this always be assumed?

Comment: That's the mean value theorem.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the clarification!